# Как навешать обработчик событий на созданный элемент?

Tags: javascript

```
saveCard.addEventListener('click', () => {
    flashcards.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `
    
    <div class = "flashcard">
        <h2 class = 'Hone' style = "border-top:1px solid red; padding: 15px; margin-top:30px">${question.value}</h2>
        <h2 class = 'Htwo' style = "text-align:center; display:none; color:red">${answer.value}</h2>
    </div>

    `)
})
```

Вот я создал карточку и теперь мне надо при нажатии на блок **Htwo** менялся цвет текста, которых находится в **Htwo**. Как мне навесить событие на блок, который я только что создал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как добавлять обработчик вам уже написали, я же напишу как при желании можно обойтись одним обработчиком.

Для этого надо всего лишь повесить событие на любой родительский элемент (в примерах я вешаю его на body, но обычно можно найти более подходящего родителя).

Для начала, вот так это делается на jquery (за что эту библиотеку и любят - ну или любили когда-то):

```js
$(document.body).on('click', '.Htwo', function(event) {
    $(event.currentTarget).style('color', 'blue');
})
```

На ванильном JS это делается чуть сложнее, но тоже ничего сложного:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    const target = event.target.closest('.Htwo');
    if (!target) return;

    target.style.color = 'blue';
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Это делается как и при обычном навешивании события. Ищется элемент в DOM дереве и добавляется слушатель через `addEventListener`.

Подвох тут может крыться в том, что элементов с одним классом может быть много и если каждый раз навешивать слушателя при добавлении - то события будут накапливаться и поэтому

- либо перед добавлением нового элемента надо будет отключать слушателя с этих классов, а после добавлении вновь всем прикреплять
- либо добавлять элемент динамически через `createElement` и тогда слушателя можно повесить конкретно на данный элемент, пример

  ```
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = 'Hello, World!';
  div.onclick = function() {
      alert(111);
  };

  let anotherDiv = document.getElementById('content');
  anotherDiv.appendChild(div);
  ```

Comment: У меня всплывает такая ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Comment: по этому куску я ничего не смогу сказать. ибо я не знаю что вы пишите

Comment: Ну как бы вы на Htwo навесили обработчик, который должен был сменить display: block;

Comment: `если каждый раз навешивать слушателя при добавлении - то события будут накапливаться` - это не верно для браузера. При добавлении одного  и того же слушателя на один и тот же элемент - слушатель не добавляется.  Для NodeJs - верно. Там добавляется

Comment: @Дмытрык если добавлять через addEventListener - ещё как добавляется

Comment: @PavelMayorov, если обработчик можно добавить несколько раз  - значит ли это, что при возникновении события - обработчик и отработает несколько раз?

Comment: @Roman то, как реализовал бы я что-то - не важно, т.к. я знаю как что делать. Если вам нужно решить свою проблему, то нужно хорошо её описать и сформулировать, показав 
  Html разметку и js, который работает с этой разметкой некорректно

Comment: @Дмытрык именно это оно и означает

Comment: @PavelMayorov - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1364372/271553 - не подтверждается Ваше утверждение. Может я что-то не так делаю?

Comment: @Дмытрык а вы добавьте обработчики так, чтобы они делали одно и то же, но не были идентичны. Например, создайте их в замыкании.

Comment: @PavelMayorov так да. Но это уже разные обработчики